# How to pass options like `only_path: true` and `anchor:` to `url_for` when generating a route from an array or object (instead of from a hash)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to change a function — which currently only accepts a URL (path) *string* — to make it more flexible, so that it will also accept as input the same arguments that you can pass to `url_for`. The problem is, `url_for` returns a full URL including protocol/host, and I only want the path portion...

[`url_for`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for) has a lovely `only_path: true` option that makes it skip adding the protocol/host. This works great as long as you're passing it as part of a single hash to `url_for`:

```
main > app.url_for(controller: 'users', action: 'index', only_path: true)
=> "/users"
```

But how do you pass options when you are passing an *array* or a *model object* to `url_for`?

```
main > app.url_for(user, only_path: true)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
from /gems/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:166:in `url_for'

main > app.url_for([user, :notification_preferences], only_path: true)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
/actionpack-5.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:166:in `url_for'
```

You can't! Clearly, it's not even syntactically possible to pass an options hash if you're passing anything other than a hash, since [it](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for)s arity is `0..1` and it only takes a single argument: `url_for(options = nil)`.

---

So my question is, is there a Rails helper that takes the same options as `url_for` (including `anchor:`) but returns a path?

I suppose it wouldn't be too hard to add one, like [this one](https://grosser.it/2009/08/26/path_for-rails-helper/), that uses `URI.parse(path).path` (probably what I'll do for now)... but that seems inefficient, inelegant, and inconsistent.

**Inefficient** and **inelegant** because it generates a string containing extra unwanted information and then has to parse it, convert it to a structured data structure, and then convert it *back* to a string *without* the unwanted information.

**Inconsistent** because:

1. Rails includes a `_path` variant for every `_url` route helper. Why doesn't it have a built-in "path" variant of `url_for` (or does it and it's called something else?)?
2. *Other* routing helpers that accept an object or array—such as `polymorphic_path`— let you pass in options too:

Example:

```
main > app.polymorphic_url [user, :notification_preferences], anchor: 'foo'
=> "http://example.com/users/4/notification_preferences#foo"

main > app.polymorphic_path [user, :notification_preferences], anchor: 'foo'
=> "/users/4/notification_preferences#foo"

main > app.polymorphic_path user, anchor: 'foo'
=> "/users/4#foo"
```

`ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` actually has a `path_for`:

```
  # strategy for building urls to send to the client                        
  PATH    = ->(options) { ActionDispatch::Http::URL.path_for(options) }     
  UNKNOWN = ->(options) { ActionDispatch::Http::URL.url_for(options) }    

  def path_for(options, route_name = nil)                                   
    url_for(options, route_name, PATH)                                      
  end                                                                       

  # The +options+ argument must be a hash whose keys are *symbols*.         
  def url_for(options, route_name = nil, url_strategy = UNKNOWN)            
    options = default_url_options.merge options    
    ...
```

— just not `ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor`, apparently. Anyway, `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#path_for` is buried too deep in internals to be helpful to me; I need a helper that is callable from the controller/view.

So, what is a good solution for this that is elegant, consistent with other Rails routing helpers, and relatively efficient (no `URI.parse`)?

---

Better yet, is there any reason the method signature of the built-in `url_for` couldn't simply be modified (in a future version of Rails, by submitting a pull request) to allow both a subject (model object, array, or hash) *and* any number of optional `options` to be passed in?

Probably the original `url_for` was written before Ruby had keyword arguments. But nowadays, it's pretty trivial to do exactly that: accept an "object" plus any number of optional keyword options:

```
def url_for(object = nil, **options)
  puts "object: #{object.inspect}"
  puts "options: #{options.inspect}"
end

main > url_for ['user', :notification_preferences], anchor: 'anchor'
object: ["user", :notification_preferences]
options: {:anchor=>"anchor"}
=> nil

main > url_for ['user', :notification_preferences], only_path: true
object: ["user", :notification_preferences]
options: {:only_path=>true}
```

Is there any reason we couldn't/shouldn't change `url_for`'s method signature to `url_for(object = nil, **options)`?

How would you modify `url_for`/`full_url_for` such that it remained as backwards compatible as possible but also let you call it with an array + keyword options?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one potential solution that shows kind of what I'm looking for:

```ruby
  def url_for(object = nil, **options)
    full_url_for(object, **options)
  end

  def full_url_for(object = nil, **options)
    path_or_url_for = ->(*args) {
      if options[:only_path]
        _routes.path_for(*args)
      else
        _routes.url_for( *args)
      end
    }
    polymorphic_path_or_url = ->(*args) {
      if options[:only_path]
        polymorphic_path(*args)
      else
        polymorphic_url( *args)
      end
    }

    case object
    when nil, Hash, ActionController::Parameters
      route_name = options.delete :use_route
      merged_url_options = options.to_h.symbolize_keys.reverse_merge!(url_options)
      path_or_url_for.(merged_url_options, route_name)
    when String
      object
    when Symbol
      HelperMethodBuilder.url.handle_string_call self, object
    when Array
      components = object.dup
      polymorphic_path_or_url.(components, components.extract_options!)
    when Class
      HelperMethodBuilder.url.handle_class_call self, object
    else
      HelperMethodBuilder.url.handle_model_call self, object
    end
  end
```

(Compare to source of [original Rails version](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for))

I haven't tried running the Rails test suite against this code yet, so it very well may have missed something, but it seems to work for my simple tests so far:

```
main > app.url_for(controller: 'users', action: 'index')
=> "http://example.com/users"

main > app.url_for(controller: 'users', action: 'index', only_path: true)
=> "/users"

main > app.url_for [user, :notification_preferences]
=> "http://example.com/users/4/notification_preferences"

main > app.url_for [user, :notification_preferences], only_path: true
=> "/users/4/notification_preferences"
```

Let me know if you find any bugs in this or have any improvements or can think of a cleaner way to accomplish this.

Please do post any improved version you may have as an answer!